# Facebook login with app error Message: " Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains...."

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js, facebook-login, passport-facebook

I'm trying to implement Facebook login with Passport for my app hosted with an Herokuapp domain but I've been getting the above error message even after setting the values for app domain, website and OAUTH redirect URL.

Nothing I've seen here from previous answers seem to be working. Screenshots provided below

[image: App Website]

[image: OAuth Redirect]

[image: App Domain]

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue, what finally worked for me was to make sure that the callbackURL *exactly* matched what was in Facebook's 'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs'.

For example, if you have `https://example.com/auth/facebook/callback` as a callback URI, then you need to have it listed exactly the same within your code -

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: 'https://example.com/auth/facebook/callback',
  }, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    ...
  }),
);
```

I had been using `/auth/facebook/callback` for my `callbackURL`, but it had to be the exact value that was given to Facebook in your apps settings.

Additionally, you may need to include the `www` version of your site in both your App Domains and your Valid OAuth Redirect URIs, as Facebook will throw an error if you try to go to https://www.example.com when you have only included https://example.com.

Answer (score 2):

I have just fixed my issue. I receive the same error message when trying connect Facebook login with passport lib. My solution is to use full callback url instead. The code is below:

```
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
passport.use(
  new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    callbackURL: 'https://your_domain.com/facebook/callback'
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    done(null, {profile: profile})
  }
))
```

Hoping this is useful for you